# Caro Mio Ben: pronunciation

Tags: technique, voice, practice

I have a question. I'm currently studying bel canto with a very good teacher. However we are in disagreement about one factor. In "Caro Mio Ben", the words "languisce il cor" appear. In all of the sung versions I have heard by famous artists, they seem to elide the final "e" of "languisce" with the "i" of "il" to create the sound "el". My teacher claims this is not correct. Please clarify, so I will know how to sing these words. Thank you!

Comment: What does your teacher say is right?

Comment: @phoog who is saying that the teacher was right? Or, more interestingly: who's saying that the teacher's right? ;-)

Comment: @musicamante the teacher says that it is not correct to elide the _e_.  Presumably the teacher says that it is correct to do something other than elide the _e_.  What, according to the teacher, is the correct way to sing that phrase without eliding the _e_?

Comment: @phoog that was just a joke, but, then again, the point is not only what the teacher says, but how that opinion is reliable: can they provide a *valid* motivation for that? Because most of times they just tell you what was told them, when talking about a language they barely know.

Comment: @musicamante it doesn't matter whether the teacher's opinion is reliable, because the question is whether the teacher's opinion is correct. I therefore asked for clarification of the teacher's opinion so it would be possible to say whether the teacher's opinion is correct. One thing is clear, however, the question is not actually about eliding the "e," as the product of the supposed elision is "el."

Comment: @phoog the elision could also be "languisc-il".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127809/discussion-between-phoog-and-musicamante).

Answer (score 9):

<sup>Premise: I'm italian, and I am *really* fanatic about our language pronunciation and writing, including their meaning, context and history, especially when related to music.</sup>

Now, the keyword here is [*elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), even if this often happens as a similar aspect, [*apocope*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope).

The *elision* is when an unstressed vowel (or syllable) is omitted at the end of a word when the following has a "compatible" sound (usually, another vowel). The *apocope* is very similar, but doesn't strictly require another similar sound for the next word, and it has always been used (even nowadays) mostly for poetic expression or due to broad usage. This is, coincidentally, the case of "cor", which is the apocope of "core", another writing of *cuore* ("heart") which is also sometimes written or pronounced as "cuor" even in current language, when some stress is required for "poetry" purposes.
Actually, it's common for everyday words and sentences, like "mangiar bene" (instead of "mangiar**e** bene"): eating healthy/good food (yeah, we do enjoy our food, and we've good reasons ;-) ).

Another and related typical italian case is the word "Amore" (love), which is often reduced to "Amor" even if followed by a consonant (e.g.: "Amor mio", Manon Lescaut, et al.). Poetic emphasis is obviously more stressed when using words related to feelings. Interestingly enough, the apocope is avoided when current language normally uses it, as *not* omitting the vowel *explicitly* emphasizes the meaning, not unlike using "you ARE" instead "you're".

Now, the case of "languisce-il" is a bit different, as both elision and apocope are rarely used in Italian when some specific sounds are important part of the sillable or might create confusion: it's often avoided with sounds *based* on `s` and `z`, but that's not a rule. The "general" (and, therefore, not absolute) concept is that the meaning and elegance of sound is a primary purpose, but, most importantly, the elision/apocope must **not** create confusion in the context. Since "languisc-" (with "sc" pronounced as "sh" when followed by `i` or `e`) can be conjugated in two very different ways in italian, that could lead to confusion:

- *languisce*: he/she/it languishes [something]
- *languisci*: you [make] languish [something]

<sup>Also, you probably need to be italian (or *really* know what living in Italy is) to really and truly understand both the conjugation *and* the sound.</sup>

In this specific case, it would be a clear case of *elision*: it is followed by a vowel ("il") and the subject of the sentence is (almost) clear.

It's not "caro mio ben" ("my dear beloved"), but the heart: "languisce il cor" is "my heart struggles".
So, the "e" **could** be elided in Italian. Doing it is not grammatically wrong.

To a non-italian speaker (or italian/belcanto fanatic), that wouldn't be much of a difference. But, actually, this creates a doubt, as explained before:

- "languisc(**e**) il cor": my heart struggles
- "languisc(**i**) il cor": *you* make my heart struggle

Then there's the question of "il". In italian poetry and, therefore, librettos, the article is sometimes elided when following another vowel (so, almost always, since there are very few words that end with a consonant):

> Voi che per li occhi mi passaste 'l core
> <sup>Guido Cavalcanti, ca. XIII</sup>

As you can see, the "i" is elided even in the written form, and even if it does not follow the same vowel.

Considering the above points, pronouncing it "languisce'l cor" wouldn't be an error: it doesn't create confusion (the subject of the verb is clear) and there exist many examples of elision with a different vowel.

There's one last question here: attribution of the "song" is still undecided, which also means that there's no clear source about the actual "libretto", and so, the possible apocope.

We don't know for sure what was the original meaning, but, grammatically speaking, eliding the "e" is not *strictly* wrong: it could just change the meaning, but that's open to debate.
Current performance practice uses the full version, which means that the most accepted version (as the most famous singer performed) is by pronouncing both the "e" at the end of "languisce" and the "i" of "il".

If you *do* want to do the elision, you *could* elide the "i", but since in the second verse "sce" and "il" are on different notes, that wouldn't be very consistent.

<sup>Note: the verb "languire" is technically an *intransitive* verb, so you *could* not say "languire il cuore di qualcun altro" (as in "struggle somebody else's heart"), as it would be grammatically wrong. But, that's poetry: forms can be bent, as long as the meaning is strong enough and it's clear enough for the language.</sup>

Comment: How do we not know the original meaning?  The song comes to us in written form, not solely through oral tradition.

Comment: @phoog the fact that that attribution is undecided means that the available written versions are not 100% authoritative: there's no autographed version, no printed reference. We got lots of "inherited" versions, but their reliability is not that different than oral tradition from this point of view.

Comment: But they all show the text "languisce il cor."

Comment: I think you are mistaken (also Italian native speaker here, albeit no singer): the phenomenon in question is [synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha) and it is extremely common in Italian

Comment: I performed this song as lan-gweish el kor

Comment: @phoog I don't argue with that, but as said that *could* be the result of what has become the accepted/common practice. For what we know, the original author could have used that (or could not). What we have is an unattributed written form, and we *now* use that.

Comment: @DenisNardin synalepha *is* what it's written and how it's properly pronounced: the two vowels are "slurred" (almost like a diphthong) and compose a single sillable. I think we all agree that the written form *is* the accepted version and that there's no *alternate* practice, but *if* either the E or the I are *not* pronounced (despite the fact that it wouldn't be "philologycally" correct) then it *is* an elision: a synalepha is a *metric* figure (the vowels remain intact), not phonetical (one vowel is completely removed).

Comment: @phoog: Yes, but if all but one copy was lost to the sands of time, and all copies today are based upon that, the fact that they all agree would indicate nothing about the accuracy of the copy upon which they were based.

Comment: @supercat on the other hand, the text underlay here complies with the prevailing standard practice, so there's no reason to think that it was ever written down in any other way.

Comment: @phoog there are *many* reasons to think that it's possible that it could have been written in the other way (more likely, "languisce 'l cor", anyway). Composers often changed lyrics at a certain amount, for musical purposes or just for personal taste. We could agree that *in this case* there was *probably* no elision *in the music* (due to the repetition with a different and explicit note for the other syllable, but that's just an assumption) but since we don't have an original critical/verified version, there's no point in discussing. We just use what we got, but we **cannot** be 100% sure.

Comment: Remember that up until mid 1800 mechanical music printing was not common, and most music was in manuscript form (with many, often "inherited", errors) and liberties from copyists as much as conductors/artists. We are now accustomed to the "common practice", the "recorded work", but that only began no more than 150 years ago. Until then, there was much more freedom in performance and interpretation, which often resulted in "printed" versions that also proposed different variations on an work, including variations *on* variations written by others.

Comment: @musicamante can you cite any examples from the 18th century where Italian text underlay by an Italian-speaking composer explicitly indicated elision?  And your last comment could not be more incorrect: mechanical printing of music began in the 1400s and was common by 1600.

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure about what you're asking: do you want a practical demonstration of a composer specifying an elision that was not present in the original libretto? That would almost impossible to (easily) find one, as that would be based on the original exchange of letters between author(s) and composer. I really don't understand why you're still pointing out this aspect. And about the 2nd point, well, no: mechanical printed music was **not** as common as manuscript. Many editors still sold handwritten music throughout 1800, as producing and publishing engraved music was expansive.

Comment: ...and buying it was also too expansive for lots people (and reasons), so many musicians had manuscripts copied from others, and there were people that made cheap copies for those who couldn't afford the originals. Not to mention orchestral transcriptions, reductions and modifications for first performances in different venues (that required changes due to the available instruments or soloists skills). If you visit the archives of almost *any* orchestra older than 60-70 years you'll see that manuscripts often were the majority, and for obvious reasons: printing wasn't profitable in many cases.

Comment: Consider that contemporary music performance was much more common then, sometimes written or adapted just for the occasion, so printing it was pointless, or it could cost so much that nobody would buy it: why paying so much for something that's gonna be played just a couple of times? It's not so different from todays habits: if you get a piece to be added to your program, you probably just look for it on the web and print it, you rarely buy it if you're going to play it just that time - the difference is that they used handwritten copies.

Comment: MP music was more common for pieces played by middle class, but that's not a reference for reliable diffusion of authoritative material (again, and especially there, lots of transcriptions, often with poor quality): copyright law wasn't today's, many editors had their own versions/transcriptions of a same piece made from borrowed manuscripts or other sources. MP music was common, but not *as* common as manuscript usage. Some reference: https://publicdomainreview.org/essay/music-manuscripts-from-the-17th-and-18th-centuries-in-the-british-library . Again: there's *no* original of this.

Comment: @musicamamante I am asking for "examples from the 18th century where Italian text underlay by an Italian-speaking composer explicitly indicated elision" regardless of whether there may have been a text-only source and regardless of whether that source did or did not indicate elision.  I just don't recall having seen any such thing before the late 19th century, so I believe it would have been extremely unusual for the composer to have written anything other than "languisce il cor."  This whole discussion arises because OP incorrectly used "elide the e with the i" for what you describe as...

Comment: ..."the two vowels slurred almost like a diphthong."  Also, I don't know what you mean by "We could agree that in this case there was probably no elision in the music (due to the repetition with a different and explicit note for the other syllable)" because I don't agree at all: there is only one note, and the rhythm and scansion are such that it would be terribly awkward to split it into two notes.  Your speculations about possible lost details of the original make no sense because they would be extremely unusual features if they existed, while the version that survives is very conventional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127869/discussion-between-musicamante-and-phoog).

Answer (score 4):

The 'e' at the end of 'languisce' and the 'i' of 'il' should both be pronounced, with a legato connection.

[Cecilia Bartoli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Hlk8EDA02M&t=40s) and [Luciano Pavarotti](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQ_xRL3uxTA&t=30s) both sing it that way, both are Italian, and both are the pinnacle of singers.

NOTE: where one needs to be careful is in switching between the 'e' and 'i' vowel sounds that the purity of each is preserved. You don't want to produce "in between" vowels as you move from one to the other.

Comment: I might be wrong, but, are you saying that both Bartoli and Pavarotti actually *did* the elision? Because if that's the case, they did **not**. It might be difficult to listen, but both the E and the I are there in both cases.

Comment: @musicamante The problem was that I had the wrong definition of "elision". I've corrected my post.

Comment: @musicamante but the question also misunderstands "elision," as shown by the description "to create the sound 'el.'"